# What will Android Dialog class object do after screen rotation

Tags: android, dialog

I have a calss A extends `Dialog`(not `DialogFragment`) showing in the screen(create a A object in MainAcitivity), I have a `mContext` member value in A, and when screen rotates, I want to update the `mContext`, how can I do this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 ....
 A mDialog = new A(this);
 mDialog.showDialog();
 ....
}

public class A extends Dialog {
   Context mContext;
   ....
   public void showDialog() {
      ....
   }

   private void functionB() {
      //need to use the updated mContext;
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by update mContext? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I have a listener which is connected with mContext, if I use the old mContext after roatation and it will cause crash because former acitivity has been destroyed

Comment: Try dismissing the dialog when the Activity is destroyed. Then it will be recreated when the Activity is. You can't save the context in onSaveInstanceState.

Comment: Why not use a dialogFragment?

Comment: I have changed but still not git push, so should fix the bug on Dialog class first due to time limit.

Comment: I would recommend using a dialogFragment instead. You won't get this error as you won't need to pass the context. It will "just work". Generally, try not to override Android classes if you don't absolutely need to.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that when you rotate the device, the dialog will call onStop and then onStart. You can override them if you want, and save and restore instanceState.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html

But I'm not sure how that helps you since the question is so vague.

Comment: Does the onStop and onStart in Acitivity lifecycle or Dialog class?

Comment: I was referring to the dialog class. See the link.